# Sublime text preference to turn back on double mouse click to select word?

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3

Double mouse click use to work in Sublime Text 3 to select an entire word. Now something changed and I have to hold down the command key then double click to select the word :(

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html

So I did this and my double click to select a word is working again... now I'm slowly putting my packages back in 1 by 1 to see which one caused the issue.